# How to convert normal Java project into a Maven project in Mendix?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, mendix, sts

Can anyone please tell that how to convert normal java project into maven and springboot project in Mendix?

I made a java action call in Mendix, initially I got a normal java project then I tried to convert it into maven, once I done this successfully again it's getting back as a normal project.

I thought Mendix won't accept Maven but there is a option that we can able to convert it into maven.

so, could you please tell me that how to convert normal java project into maven project in Mendix?

Answers are really appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried to create a Maven project and add all your dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

You can use parts of business logic from Java in Mendix in a so called Java-action.

It is not possible to convert a sprintboot project into Mendix because Mendix has it's own server and will only publish Mendix pages.